# How to make script open programs in the same workspace in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, workspace

I have a script which opens different application and I want them to be opened in particular workspace ( the same where the script is run ). Is it possible without setting workspace for every particular application?

Comment: Can you maybe add an example of the script/application, where it lies and exactly what you would like to achieve? With workspace, do you mean directory?

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Application is unaware in which workspace it is running, so it's impossible for application to open another in the same workspace. It's only possible to tell for particular application in which workspace to run(with the help of devilspie for example)